# Django doesn't find allauth

Tags: python, django, python-venv

I have a venv for a project called manager. I installed allauth on venv but I get this error:

ImportError: No module named 'allauth'

pip freeze:

```
(manager) user@host:~/manager$ pip freeze
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==2.1.4
django-allauth==0.38.0
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
idna==2.8
oauthlib==2.1.0
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2018.7
requests==2.21.0
requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
urllib3==1.24.1
(manager) reiser@assets:~/manager$ pip freeze
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==2.1.4
django-allauth==0.38.0
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
idna==2.8
oauthlib==2.1.0
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2018.7
requests==2.21.0
requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
urllib3==1.24.1
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'invoices',
    'feedback',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

]
```

django runserver error:

```
user@host:~/manager/src$ python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7ff29b7c8d08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/reiser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/reiser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/reiser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/reiser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/reiser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/reiser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/reiser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/reiser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'allauth'
```

Python version used is 3.5 also when building the venv:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.5   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.5   2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

What am I doing wrong?

I also have to mention that before restarting the computer it worked without errors. Computer is a Debian 9.

Comment: For me it looks like you've forgotten to activate your venv. (Because the Django used doesn't seem to be in your venv.) It should look like `(manager) user@host:~/manager/src$ python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the module could not be found.

You probably just need to install the 3rd party module called allauth on your server (or add it to requirements.txt).

```
pip install django-allauth
```

You can run pip freeze locally to see which modules are installed.

To install a specific version of django-allauth, use:

```
pip install django-allauth==0.32.0
```